# making button go to next line if correct tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently learning python in school and its winter break so I really wanted to learn some GUI for python so I started learning tkinter. Currently I am trying to make it so everytime user gets the answer correct it will move on to the next line in the file but I have no idea how to do it, I have tried all day doing it just to make sure I wasnt missing anything but couldnt find what I was looking for, if anyone could please help me I would be so happy.

```
def correctquestion(e):
correct.configure(text="Correct")


def incorrectquestion(e):
    correct.configure(text="Incorrect")


def lines(e):
    file_name = open("state_capitals.txt", "r")
    line = file_name.readline().strip().split(",")

    return line

def nextquestion(e):
    line = lines(e)
    data = answerBox.get()

    if line[1] == data:
        correctquestion(e)
        questionBox.configure(text=line[0])
    else:
        incorrectquestion(e)
        questionBox.configure(text=line[0])

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=0)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

line = lines(root)


AnswerButton = Button(root, text="Submit")
AnswerButton.grid(row=3, sticky=W, padx=(80, 10))
AnswerButton.bind("<Button-1>", nextquestion)

questionBox = Label(root, text=line[0], bg="red", fg="white")
questionBox.config(font=("Courier", 30))
questionBox.grid(row=0, sticky=W + E, ipady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you always open file and read only first line - better open file only once and read all lines. ie `readlines()` (with `s` at end) or `read().split('\n')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better read all file and keep all lines in memory - it will be easier.

Example code - not tested - I don't have file with questions :)

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def read_file():
    file_ = open("state_capitals.txt")

    # create list of lines
    lines = file_.read().split('\n')

    # split every line in columns
    lines = [l.split(',') for l in lines]

    return lines

def next_question():
    global current_question # inform function to use global variable instead local because we will assign new value

    data = answer_Box.get()

    if all_lines[current_question][1] == data:
        correct.configure(text="Correct")
        current_question += 1
        if current_question < len(all_lines):
            question_box.configure(text=all_lines[current_question][0])
        else:
            question_box.configure(text="THE END")
    else:
        correct.configure(text="Incorrect")

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

all_lines = read_file()
current_question = 0 # create global variable

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

answer_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=next_question)
answer_button.grid(row=3, sticky='w', padx=(80, 10))

question_box = tk.Label(root, text=all_lines[current_question][0],
                        bg="red", fg="white", font=("Courier", 30))
question_box.grid(row=0, sticky='we', ipady=30)

correct = tk.Label(root)
correct.grid(row=1, sticky='we', ipady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)